# Request for Reference - What is this tree algorithm called?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

I devised an algorithm in the process of developing some code. I would like to know if it has a name or if it is an instance of a more general category.

The algorithm is outlined below:

In brief this algorithm takes arbitrary elements which can be merged.

1. Start with an abstract list. The elements of the list will be the leaves in your tree. Assume for the sake of simplicity that there are 2^n elements in the list.
2. Pair up the elements in the abstract list so you get 2^(n-1) pairs. The pairing is simple: the (2n-1)th element is matched with (2n)th element. You obtain a new abstract list from the results of merging these pairs. Now you can construct a node corresponding to each merged element which has as child nodes the elements from which the merged element was derived.
3. Iterate step 2 until there is only 1 element left.
4. You now have a binary tree which traces the "ancestry" of each element.

Right now, my best guess is that this is some kind of tree-fold (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism#List_fold). But it keeps track of the datastructure created by the fold process, and it allows the fold process to be conducted in parallel.

In practice the elements are lists of objects, only some of which are compatible. Hence not every merge step is successful and therefore sometimes it becomes necessary to traverse the child nodes and find new lists of objects to input.

Comment: it's not clear how do you create those pairs (how do you chose which element to pair with which). Could you clarify?

Comment: Certainly - I'll make that clear in the original question - but the idea is just that the pairs are created from neighboring elements in the abstract list.

Comment: In your use case, what do the nodes represent?

Comment: This is exactly the mergesort algorithm, just with the "merge 2 sorted lists in linear time to produce a 3rd sorted list" step left "open" as a placeholder.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The nodes represent the outcome of merge events - I can go into more detail if you want.

Comment: @j_random_hacker haha I think you are right - its just a merge algorithm that keeps the tree history. The difference in my case is that the merge function is slightly more complicated - and hence I need to keep the tree structure just in case one the merges fails.

Comment: @j_random_hacker can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept and close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithm might well be known by some other name, but one thing that it is is the mergesort algorithm, just with the "merge 2 sorted lists in linear time to produce a 3rd sorted list" step left "open" as a placeholder.